The history of ◯ being used to denote zero
What is the history behind ◯? Can someone shed some light on when it started getting used to represent zero in numbers and the like. For a kanji, it is quite peculiar as it looks like a kanjified 0. Is it read まる because, well, it is 丸 or is there another historical reason? Any reference would be welcome.

Apparently ◯ was first a 則天文字, developed by the Chinese empress 武則天 of the Tang dynasty. During her rule, she developed quite a few new characters to replace existing ones to promote her reign(you can find a list in the Wikipedia link above), and ◯ was her new version for the character 星. Later when her reign would fall and the 李 family would resume power, all her creations were abolished and original characters were returned except for two:

曌(sun and moon in the sky) which is the new character for 照, used in her name 武曌（武照）, now we only use this character to write her name and use 照 everywhere else.
◯ which is the new character for 星. People restored the use of 星 for "star" but since the ◯ is convenient to write people kept it as an alternative for 零.

All the other characters she made are completely gone in history. However, in some inscriptions made during her era, we could still see some of the 則天文字 being used. All in all, they're very short-lived.

Fantastic answer, thank you!

When was the first time ◯ was attested in Chinese writing? I wonder if there was a gap between ◯ = 星 and ◯ = 零.
